# Why isn't my selenium browser logged into sites that firefox is always logged into?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a site that is behind authentication. When I use firefox, I am always already logged on the site (even after a reboot) and I can go straight into the pages.

When I open selenium and tell it to use my firefox profile, the selenium browser isn't logged in. Then I have to go through about 4 or 5 min of clicking pictures to show that I'm a person. But if I open firefox myself immediately afterwards, I am still logged in - no problem.

So I really don't understand what is happening. I know that my firefox profile is being loaded: When I initialize the browser, it takes around 60 seconds for the profile to be copied over before the browser opens up. My code is below:

```
    from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
    from selenium import webdriver

    url_start = 'https://authenticatedsection.some site.com/'

    fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('C:/Users/Claudia/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profile/minvococ.default-release')
    browser = Firefox(fp)

    #initialize browser
    browser.get(url_start)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're logged in because of the cookies stored by your firefox browser. Selenium opens a new browser process with no cookies. If you only need to enter a user name and password to login, this can be done with selenium. If you need to pass a "human-test" (captcha) such as the picture clicking task you're describing, this cannot be done via scraper: it is specifically designed to prevent bots from logging onto that page.
Why do you want your scraper to log into your firefox profile?

Comment: I was under the impression that by loading my firefox profile into selenium, the selenium browser would have all the cookies my firefox profile does (well, all the persistent cookies, not the session cookies, but as I have indicated, the fact that I am auto logged in means the login verification is not happening on session cookies, i think)